# wrong value with pyopencl output

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am writing a code in which I use pyOpenCL and in a part of this code, I need to import an array to the openCL function (as *p* in the example) for several times and an especial index of this array has to increase by another parameter (as *src* in the example whose elements are always 1 as an example). I wrote the following code but it doesn't work properly.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ['PYOPENCL_CTX']='0:1'

ctx=cl.create_some_context()
queue=cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

mf=cl.mem_flags

prg=cl.Program(ctx,"""
__kernel void src_injection(__global float *p,int src_i,int src_j, float src)
{
 int nx=get_global_size(1);
 int idx=src_i*nx+src_j;
 p[idx]+=src;

 }
""").build()


nz, nx=50,50

nt=5

p =np.zeros((nz,nx),dtype=np.float32)
p_buff  = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=p)

src=np.ones(nt,dtype=np.float32)        
i=np.int32(2);
j=np.int32(2);             
for k in range(nt):
    prg.src_injection(queue,(nz,nx),None,
               p_buff,i,j,src[k])
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue,p,p_buff)
    print(p[i,j])
```

If I set **nx** and **nz** as small value (ex. 5 for both), I get the correct result in other way, the answer doesn't seem correct.

for example, I am looking for an answer like

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

from my code but I get

```
2.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
8.0
```

Could anyone tell me, what I have been doing in the wrong way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the kernel as below and It worked well. By the way, I am still eager to if there is a way to avoid using that ***if*** in the kernel. So, let me know if you have a tip for me. Thanks all!

```
prg=cl.Program(ctx,"""
__kernel void src_injection(__global float *p,int src_i,int src_j, float src)
{
 int nx=get_global_size(1);
 int i=get_global_id(0);
 int j=get_global_id(1);

 if (i==src_i && j==src_j){
         p[i*nx+j]+=src;
         }


 }
""").build()
```

Comment: If you change src to an array of floats, you should be able to update the entire matrix at once, using `p[i*nx+j]=src[i*nx+j]`. This way you can remove the `if` statement. On the host (python) side, you will need to put all of your src values into an array and load it into a opencl buffer. Your original implementation seems to loop through indices on the host side, and then make many calls to the kernel function. This is an antipattern in opencl. You should design your program to perform all `src_injection` tasks in one kernel call.